# How to pass XML file to JMS queue

Tags: xml, jms

I have `.xml` files and I want to send the content to the JMS queue. In this should I convert this xml to textmessage and send? or is there a way that we can directly send the xml.

And also I'd like to know is it possible to send objects (ex: objects of `MyClass.java`) to the JMS queue?

Please someone guide me.

Comment: duplicate with my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891558/sending-a-xml-message-to-jms-using-c-sharp/9891723#9891723

Comment: Sending xml as ByteMessage is not a good idea: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849828/when-sending-xml-to-jms-should-i-use-textmessage-or-bytesmessage?answertab=active#tab-top for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TextMessage to send XML. But since the XML is already stored in files, I would look at the possibility to send just the raw byte content, using a BytesMessage. If you go for first alternative, be careful about using correct encoding when redin the file content.

Java objects can definitively be sent as JMS messages, as long as they ar serializable.

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("/path/file.xml");
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();


If im using the first alternative is this the way should I go?

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit wary of the use of Writer in a stream result--not 100% sure of the consequences w.r.t encodings and such. If you use a BytesMessage, you don't have to go through the parsing and serialization step.