# Sending a XML message to JMS using C#

Tags: c#, xml, jms

I would like to send a xml file to a jms queue. How would i achieve this? Do i create a ITextMessage/IObjectMessage etc...

Will someone please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the c# client library for your chosen JMS broker (if there is one) That should have examples on how to do it.

Spring.net also has support for some JMS brokers through its NMS module. See [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/nms-quickstart.html)

The best way to send xml is via the text message.