# When sending XML to JMS should I use TextMessage or BytesMessage

Tags: java, xml, serialization, character-encoding, jms

I have found some quite conflicting information on the web and I think that each different JMS provider may also alter the answer too.

I'm trying to understand when sending XML into a JMS system (e.g. ActiveMQ) whether I should use a

- `BytesMessage`: I can guarantee that the XML is serialized correctly and the preamble will match the actual encoding.  Furthermore I can be sure that the client will be able to get the raw representation correctly.
- `TextMessage`: There are APIs in many of the queue implementations for sending XML easily.  I also understand that there are "encoding" information attached to the messages.  But I risk encoding the message (and writing it's preamble) in one format and receiving it as another.

Does anyone have a definitive answer, or at least some reasons why you would choose one over the other?

Comment: no definite answer, sorry mate. My 2cts: XML is a text format, hence, use TextMessage. If you be sending binary data, say a zip or jpg, -then- use BytesMessage. Let stuff make sense on its own (w/o documentation). It keeps (developers/testers/maintenance) life easier.

Comment: try working for a defence project and telling your manager "We aren't going to document it to make it easier...".  Still I get what you are saying.  Base 64 encoded UTF8 isn't too bad, without having to resort to something like MTOM.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [jos'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755654/jos) comment to your question. First off, you should choose the kind of message type that best expresses the *semantics* of your content. Reading the [`TextMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) Javadoc, I'd go for that:

> This message type can be used to transport text-based messages, including those with XML content.

So if you do run into trouble with your text message encoding, then there's probably some mis-configuration on the client / server side. But that shouldn't be a motivation for abusing a different message type that was not primarily intended for text transfer, such as [`BytesMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html).

N.B: Even with `BytesMessage`, you can get the encoding wrong. Imagine:

```
// Send that data through JMS
byte[] data1 = "source text".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

// Receive the byte stream on the other side. Ooops
String data2 = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: True, but the libraries I'm using in .Net will look for byte order marks given a stream of data and correctly identify the encoding.  Plus my xml has the preamble.  But what I'm hearing is that the jury is out.

Comment: Interestingly (I'm working a similar type issue currently) - in Java 8, the code snippet works: data1= "[B@3d4eac69" and data2="source text", which is the original text.